# what will be type where result get stored when expressions are passed as parameters in c

Tags: c, function

If i am passing an mathematical expression like `func(a*b/c)` where type of a may be `double`, `b` might be `long int` etc.

Is there any problem in passing parameters like that? What happens if the resultant value is too long? Any issues in using expressions as function parameters?

Comment: how is `func()` defined?

Comment: There is no guarantee that `a*b/c` is evaluated from left to right: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix the *definiion* of a function with the *calling* of the function. The definition says what the type of the argumens are; in the calling, the compiler faithfully executes (compiles) the expression, casting it to the appropriate type of the function's argument as it has been defined.

```
void func1(double a);
void func2(int a);
...
func1( 2 * 3/3);
func2( 2.0 * 3/3);
```

In the first call to func1(), the expression is evaluated as integers and then the result is pushed onto the stack as a double. In the second cal to func2() the expression is evaluated as doubles and then the result is cast to integer and pushed onto the stack. In the second case the compiler might give a warning about possible loss of precission in the conversion; in the first case it will not issue such a warning as all integer results fit a double.

Answer (score 1):

> C11 introduces the
>   [_Generic](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html)
>   selection expression which provides a mechanism to make compile-time
>   choices based on type allowing type-generic macros to be created using
>   standard C constructs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fn_as_int(int val){return val * 2;}
double fn_as_double(double val){return val * 2;}
long fn_as_long(long val){return val * 2;}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 100;
    double b = 5.0;
    long c = 2;

    int x = _Generic(a*b/c, int: 1, double: 2, long: 3, default: 0);

    switch (x) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            printf("As integer = %d\n", fn_as_int(a*b/c));
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("As double = %f\n", fn_as_double(a*b/c));
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("As long = %ld\n", fn_as_long(a*b/c));
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unknown\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: https://ideone.com/3JdXy7